# I can't find why my project doesn't work, issues with using modules in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have to do a project in javascript even though i'm not really competent with this language and i've been stuck with the same kind of problem for far too long. Concretely i'm trying to use git repositories to generate post-quantum security key to create authentication token. But each time i run my server (npx serve -l 8000) i run across an error with the require. Here is my code :

main.js file :

```
// https://github.com/tniessen/node-pqclean 1st repositories i found
const PQClean = require('pqclean');

const {
  publicKey,
  privateKey
} = await PQClean.kem.generateKeyPair('mceliece8192128');

const { key, encryptedKey } = await publicKey.generateKey();
console.log("Bob's key", Buffer.from(key).toString('hex'));

const receivedKey = await privateKey.decryptKey(encryptedKey);
console.log("Alice's key", Buffer.from(receivedKey).toString('hex'));
// end of test code of the first repositories

// https://github.com/antontutoveanu/crystals-kyber-javascript 2nd repositories i found
const kyber = require('crystals-kyber');

// To generate a public and private key pair (pk, sk)
let pk_sk = kyber.KeyGen768();
let pk = pk_sk[0];
let sk = pk_sk[1];

// To generate a random 256 bit symmetric key (ss) and its encapsulation (c)
let c_ss = kyber.Encrypt768(pk);
let c = c_ss[0];
let ss1 = c_ss[1];

// To decapsulate and obtain the same symmetric key
let ss2 = kyber.Decrypt768(c,sk);

// Test function with KATs
kyber.Test768();

// end of test code of the second repositories


function createAuthToken(userId) {
    const crypto = window.crypto
    const secretKey = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(32));
    const data = userId + Date.now(); 
    const dataArray = new TextEncoder().encode(data);
    
    return crypto.subtle.sign( 
    {
        name: "HMAC",
        hash: { name: "SHA-256" },
    },
      secretKey,
      dataArray
    ).then(signature => {
      return Array.from(new Uint8Array(signature))
        .map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
        .join("");
    });
}


async function createSession(userId) {
    const sessionId = Date.now();
    const authToken = await createAuthToken(userId);
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('sessionId')){ 
        localStorage.removeItem('sessionId');
    }
    if(localStorage.getItem('authToken')){ 
        localStorage.removeItem('authToken');
    }
    localStorage.setItem('sessionId', sessionId); 
    localStorage.setItem('authToken', authToken);
    
    return { sessionId, authToken };
}
```

index.html file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="module" src="./main.js" defer></script>
    <title>Handmade Token webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <H1>Something</H1>
</body>
</html>
```

I know for sure i didn't do something or i didn't do it right but i can't find what. (For now the most important for me is to at least make the repo import works)

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: You have to explain exactly what the error is for people to be able to help.